# CSS pixels vs device pixels on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css

If I specify the width of a `<div>` tag using CSS as 96px, how many device pixels should that occupy on the screen of a first generation iPhone?

I added `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` to the page, took a screenshot on the simulator, and measured the `div` to be 96 device pixels wide.  Now, I read the [W3 spec for CSS pixels](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) and it states that 1px is 1/96th of an inch.  So 96 CSS pixels should translate to 1 inch.  Since the original iPhone has a [DPI of 163](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Apple), one inch on the screen should occupy 163 device pixels.  Why am I not getting that measurement?  In other words, should 96 CSS pixels be equal to 1 inch?

I saw that the spec also mentions anchoring to a reference pixel.  It seems to me that the reference pixel is simply a device pixel in this case.  If I was to work backwards to get the CSS pixel values from a screenshot, would it generally be correct to assume that one device pixel equals one CSS pixel on the iPhone (non-retina display)?

Comment: That depends on the zoom level right?

Comment: Yes, but the <meta> tag should fix the zoom level to 100% so it shouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iphone pixels are like any other pixel. A 96px wide `<div>` is always 96px wide in any device. DPI (Dots Per Inch) just tell you the ratio between physical pixels (dots) on a screen (or paper) and inches and don't represent any size. DPI are only a **ratio** between pixels and a real world unit of measurement.

A 96px `div` would look 6x bigger in a 50 DPI screen than a 300 DPI screen.

DPI vary depending on the device or print/scan quality, therefore 1 inch is NOT always equal to 96 pixels. W3C is just saying that the absolute length units are fixed *in relation to each other* (it is just an arbitrary approximation to make CSS units consistent). This does not mean that real world units of measurement (inches, cm) can be given a fixed ratio to pixels.

The best help i can give you to understand this is that 1px is only and always equal to 1px. Any comparison between pixels and real world units depends on the DPI of a specific device, not on a standard like the W3C.

> The absolute length units are fixed in relation to each other and
>   anchored to some physical measurement. They are mainly useful when the
>   output environment is known.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that part of the W3C spec again. I took the statement that 1px equals 1/96th of an inch to always refer to a physical inch, like an inch on a ruler.  That's not the case as I found out when I changed the width of the <div> to 1in.  It's exactly the same width as 96px and a bit more than 1/2 of a physical inch.