# Can window size differ from device size?

Tags: html, css, magento, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I have a Magento 1.9 site, with foundation 5 as a framework.  As I tested on my iphone 6 plus which have a device (w*h) of 414px*731px.  but when I run it against jQuery's `$(window).width()` I get 980 instead.

I checked all my css, on `html`, `body`, `container` which some have `width:100%` but none I can tell it's 980px.  please help.

Comment: Look up [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). They can accomplish what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CSS pixels and device pixels are not the same. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735997/css-pixels-vs-device-pixels-on-iphone) and [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks you so much.  I think adding the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">` will solve compatibility between devices?

Comment: Be careful with `maximum-scale=1.0`, it prevents the user from zooming in the page. This `meta` will adapt the viewport to make it fit the `device-width` which is the CSS width of your device